# Google speech-to-text API sample code will not run

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, speech-to-text

I've been constantly rereading the instructions (setting up the project, setting the environmental variable to the file path of the JSON file with my service account key, installing/initializing gcloud etc.) but I just can't run the sample code at all and I can't figure out why. The sample code is:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
const gcsUri = '.resources/audio.raw';
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = 'en-US';

const config = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: languageCode,
};

const audio = {
  uri: gcsUri,
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
// can wait for now, or get its result later.
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
// Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
const [response] = await operation.promise();
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
  .join('\n');
console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
```

Terminal says the following error:

```
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
                      ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

I don't understand why it's an unexpected identifier. Wasn't const client created?

Comment: `await` can only be used in an `async` function

Answer (score 1):

"await" is used for async function, let's put your code into a async function

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
const gcsUri = '.resources/audio.raw';
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = 'en-US';

const config = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: languageCode,
};

const audio = {
  uri: gcsUri,
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};
async function main () {
// Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
// can wait for now, or get its result later.
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
// Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
const [response] = await operation.promise();
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
  .join('\n');
console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword can only be used in functions that are asynchronous.

What you could to is wrap part of the code in a promise function and then callign that promise:

```
const detectSpeach = async () => {
  // Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
  // can wait for now, or get its result later.
  const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
  // Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  const transcription = response.results
    .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
    .join('\n');
  console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
};

detectSpeach();
```

more on this: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

```
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
                  ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

> I don't understand why it's an unexpected identifier. Wasn't `const client` created?

The answer is that, yes, `const client` was initialised but `await` is not treated as a keyword in ordinary JavaScript scripts. Outside of an `async` function (or generator function), `await` is usually a valid identifier, so the sequence of `await` followed by `client` is not a valid expression because `client` is an unexpected identifier.

To use `await` as an operator it must be coded in an `async` function or generator. Using `await` as an identifier in new code is probably unwise.

**Background:**

- ES5.1 did not have `await` as a reserved or future reserved word,
- ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) introduced `await` as a future reserved word in the context of an ECMAScript module.
- ECMAScript 2019 includes `await` as a reserved word but provides it can be used as an identifier unless [the goal [symbol] of the syntactic grammar is *Module*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-early-errors)

My understanding of this patchwork mess is that both `await` and `async` are detected by modifying the JavaScript parser to detect what would have been syntax errors (`async function`, `await identifier`, `for await ... of`) and process them further in some, but not all, contexts.